# sink function with future.callr

Tags: r, sink, r-future, future.callr

I have this `R` script:

**test.R**

```
library(future.callr)   
plan(callr)

executeInternalActivity<-function(){

 sink(file = "output.txt",append = TRUE)    
 print(Sys.time())
 Sys.sleep(3)
 print(Sys.time())    
 sink()

}

executeInternalActivity()    
#future({executeInternalActivity()})
```

When `test.R` is executed: `source("test.R")` (Note the calling to `executeInternalActivity`), the `output.txt` is created properly

```
[root@db1 Rscripts]# cat output.txt
[1] "2023-08-27 15:51:25 GMT"
[1] "2023-08-27 15:51:28 GMT"
```

However, if we change the calling to `executeInternalActivity` to do it with `future`:

```
#executeInternalActivity()
future({executeInternalActivity()})
```

... and then execute it:

```
source("test.R")
```

Only the first `print` appears in the `output.txt` file:

```
[root@db1 Rscripts]# cat output.txt
[1] "2023-08-27 16:10:55 GMT"
```

I would like all prints to appear in the `output.txt` file. How can I fix it?

Comment: New package to me, but don't you need to add a `value()` call to retrieve the output of `future()` ?

Comment: Yes. thats true: I found this "Note that the captured standard output (stdout) will be relayed each time value() is called" from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-2-output.html). So, `future()` evals the expression, and `value()` returns the output. Using `value()`, works as expected. However, with `value()`, the prompt of console waits till the end of the process (It is something I want to avoid). It seems the problem is the `source(test.R)`. If I execute the script from outside R: `nohup R CMD BATCH test.R &` it works as expected.

Comment: maybe `fflush()`